# Problemas con con GitLab

Tags: gitlab, phpunit

Buenas tardes amigos tengo el siguiente problema con Gitlab ya que lo tengo instalado en un servidor con linux y estoy haciendo pruebas con mi maquina local con entorno de windows 7.

Quiero ejecutar prueba unitarias con phpunit pero la consola de gitlab me da el siguiente error
"phpunit" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,

si lo hago desde el cmd o powershell funciona perfecto ya que estan registrada como variables de etorno para windows, pero en GitLab no me lo reconoce, ya instale GitLab-Runner per Windows les comparto mi archivo .gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
- init
- tests
- despliegue

hello:
stage: init
script:
- echo "hello world 1"



test:
stage: tests
script:
- powershell -Command "C://xampp//htdocs//pruebas//dev.bat"

deploy: 
stage: despliegue

script: 
- cd /xampp/htdocs/pruebas/pruebas
- git pull http://root:12345678@192.9.200.251/root/pruebas.git
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pude resolver el problema, si algunos presentan este mismo error con Windows aqui le dejo como lo realice

Para solucionar este problema, la causa era las variables de entorno en Windows, y realice lo siguiente.

Mi ruta de phpunit esta ubicada en C:\bin, esa dirección la registre como variable de entorno de usuario y de igual forma como variable de entorno del sistema.

Ademas también tuve que registrar como variable de entorno la ruta de mi GitLab-Runner que esta en la siguiente dirección: C:\GitLab-Runner, luego reiniciar mi gitlab-runner de la siguiente manera.

gitlab-runner.exe restart

y funciono perfecto phpunit
comparto mi archivo .gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
— tests
CI_DEBUG_TRACE: “true”

test:

 stage: tests
 script:
  — phpunit
```

Comment: Me alegra que pudieras resolver el problema. Te recomendaría que editaras tu respuesta para añadir al menos algunas pinceladas básicas de cual es la solucion, para que conste en el sitio. Las respuestas que son solo un enlace se consideran de baja calidad en la comunidad, dado que si por lo que sea el enlace al que se apunta desaparece, la respuesta queda sin sentido.

Comment: Gracias - Pikoh por la sugerencia, ya ajuste los cambios

Comment: Estupendo! Muchas gracias por aceptar mi sugerencia y espero que sigas compartiendo a la comunidad. Un saludo :)